# Regex. How to get words after semicolon

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get all the words(surnames) only after every semicolon appearance.

I've tried this regex, but it's not working correctly:

```
(?:.*?;)([a-zA-ZñÑ]+)
```

**Here's the example line I want to filter with regex:**

> Walter Shelter, Mary; Johnson Smith, Robert; Dickinson Queen, Patty

**Here's the result I want to get:**

> Walter Johnson Dickinson

Beforehand, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:(?<=^)|(?<=; ))\w+
```

Or this shorter one:

```
(?<=; |^)\w+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sQ3rM4/1)

**Code:**

```
$s = 'Walter Shelter, Mary; Johnson Smith, Robert; Dickinson Queen Patty';
preg_match_all('/(?<=; |^)\w+/', $s, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Walter
    [1] => Johnson
    [2] => Dickinson
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! you're the man! It's working properly, now I'm tying to split this with another regex (and big) expression. :)

Comment: It's so good to realize there is a platform like regex101! But I can't join the two expressions, I really appreciate if you can help me.

Here's my original string and regex:

https://regex101.com/r/oQ1fJ1/1

As you can see I only find the way to get the first surname. Thanks!

Comment: Extracting some text from HTML and above regex should not be combined in single regex anyway. Ideally HTML parsing should be done using DOM parser and then use above regex to extract surnames.

Comment: Thanks again! yes I know, but I'm learning how to use regex and practicing with this kind of exercises.