# Join two regex or do the same inside the same regex

Tags: php, html, regex, string

Got this string:

```
<td>26/02/2015</td><td>09:00</td><td>26/02/2015</td><td>12:00</td><td>3</td><td>I1/121</td><td>10074 codification</td><td>103126 Codification, Cooperation and development - 11</td><td>Walter Shelter, Mary; Johnson Smith, Robert; Dickinson Queen Patty</td><td>without group</td>
```

And I want to extract the next information:

```
02 103126-11 Walter Johnson Dickinson
```

I can figure out how to get the `02 103126-11 Walter` part with the regex:

```
$nodup_filtertoexec = preg_match('/\d{2}\/(\d{2})\/\d{4}.*?\d+\s.*?(\d+)\s.*?-\s(\d+).*?(?:.*?<td>){1}([a-zA-ZñÑ]+).*/m', $filtered, $matches);
```

So the problem is I can't realize how to get the first surname value part of every second value before `;`.

Here's the link to regex101 with the actual regex [regex to get 02 103126-11 Walter values](https://regex101.com/r/oQ1fJ1/2)

The regex to get the three surnames is:

```
(?:(?<=^)|(?<=; ))\w+
```

Here's the regex101 example:

[regex to get the Walter Johnson Dickinson values](https://regex101.com/r/sQ3rM4/1)

So it would be good to know how to join the two regex expressions in one.

**UPDATE:**
**Here is my latest try, not working as expected yet. Only need to know how to iterate the last part of the regex to get "Proof" and "Prooftwo" or "Proofthree" (if exist), etc... from the html. Any help will be appreciated.**

I've been testing with (?<=;) and (?=;) without luck.

https://regex101.com/r/oQ1fJ1/4

Comment: Are you not able to get the data directly from the source? Extracting stuff from HTML can be tedious and, if it changes, even unreliable.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen thanks a lot for your response. The stuff from HTML will not change, but there will be less or more surnames values. For example: Williams Smith, Timothy; Doyle Byrne, Samuel; Toole Murphy, Alexandra; Murray Neil, Jack; Cullen Farrell, Jayden

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests and this works if you have 3 words to get:

```
\d{2}\/(\d{2})\/\d{4}.*?\d+\s.*?(\d+)\s.*?-\s(\d+).*?(?:.*?<td>){1}([a-zA-ZñÑ]+)[^;]+; ([a-zA-ZñÑ]+)[^;]+; ([a-zA-ZñÑ]+)
```

The key point is this to get the first word after `;`:

```
{1}([a-zA-ZñÑ]+)[^;]+; ([a-zA-ZñÑ]+)[^;]+; ([a-zA-ZñÑ]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/tM9nW3/1

You of course can group them `(regex){2}` if you think the number of elements won't be static.

Comment: Thanks!! The words aren't always 3. They are variable in every iteration.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25986662/1983854 --> "You cannot have an unknown number of capture groups". So you should capture everything and then split it.

Comment: @ferdoqui Wow, it's not as simple as I thought. I've got an </td> at the end of the surnames group.. Could it helps in some way?

Comment: Sorry I meant fedorqui. The structure is always the same, but the number of separated items by ; may be different.
For example: Williams Smith, Timothy; Doyle Byrne, Samuel; Toole Murphy, Alexandra; Murray Neil, Jack; Cullen Farrell, Jayden </td>

Comment: Something like: https://regex101.com/r/oQ1fJ1/3 but I don't know how to iterate ([a-zA-ZñÑ]+)[^;]+; ([a-zA-ZñÑ]+)

Comment: @user3321425 yes, I've been playing for a bit while but I couldn't find a solution for that, since it needs to have some capturing and some not capturing groups

Comment: I truly appreciate it!! I'm struggling right now. Hope I can figure it out.Thank you a lot!

Comment: @user3321425 I think this is quite tricky and I am not able to find a solution for it. What I would do is to strip the string within `<td>` and `</td>` and then apply the approach anubhava suggested you in your previuos question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28959848/1983854).